# Converting hide/show function in mootools to pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following function found in [a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7002409/1417223):

```
function toggleTooltip(id) {
    var e = document.id(id);
    if( !e.toggleCallback ) {
        e.toggleCallback = function() { toggleTooltip(id); };
    }
    if(e.style.display=='block') {
        e.style.display='none';
        document.removeEvent('click', e.toggleCallback);
    } else {
        e.style.display='block';
        document.addEvent('click', e.toggleCallback);
    }
}
```

On click it shows a specific element and then on click anywhere it hides it. A working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/au32j/1/).

I like to use this as a pure javascript function (i.e. no mootools dependency), but I don't really understand how I'd turn the functions `toggleCallback`/`removeEvent`/`addEvent` to normal javascript.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the `document.id()` method? Shouldn't it be `document.getElementById()`?

Comment: I'd guess it's a mootools functionality as well? But you're right, I'm pretty sure it's the equivalent of `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Mootools has a `document.id()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```js
// Might want to use document DOMContentLoaded event instead of load.
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
  document.querySelectorAll('a.tooltip').forEach(function(link) {
    var tooltip = document.getElementById(link.id + '_tooltip'),
      callback = function(e) {
        if (tooltip.style.display === 'block') {
          tooltip.style.display = 'none';
          document.removeEventListener('click', callback);
        } else {
          tooltip.style.display = 'block';
          document.addEventListener('click', callback);
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
      };
    link.addEventListener('click', callback);
  });
});
```

```html
<a class="tooltip" id="link1" href="#">Show tooltip</a>
<div style="display:none" id="link1_tooltip">Click anywhere to dismiss</div>
```

---

Take a look at:

- [EventTarget.removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)
- [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

---

### [Revised jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/au32j/45/)